# What are the differences between 'Find' and 'Get' verbs on methods in the Repository or Data Access Methods?

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

Whether using the Repository pattern with an Interface or just implementing DataAccess methods in an application, I often see methods with either a 'Get' or 'Find' verb preceding the method description. I struggle a bit with differentiating between the (2), because I see conflicting examples when looking at DDD repository examples, or any other Architecture using a similar naming convention. For example take a look at the following:

```
Function FindAllEmployees() As List(Of Employee)

Function GetAllEmployees() As List(Of Employee)
```

Let's not look too closely at the subject of 'Employee', it is just an example; it could be anything. I am really interested if there are some guidelines on when to describe a method with a 'Get' vs. a 'Find' verb at the beginning.

Can anyone explain this or elaborate please? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, FindAllEmployees indicates that it might accept a predicate with which to filter the results, whereas GetAllEmployees would do just that, return the complete list.

Comment: Just to clarify, my interpretation is that the results are *references* to the Employees.  Saying "results" is just a tad vague.

Comment: The 'predicate' would be a list of conditions applied at runtime to filter the results, or it would not be that dynamic?

Comment: it could be a SQL style string, a Linq expression, some other way of specifying names and values. But yes, it would execute at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

`Get` throws an error if it doesn't exist (and usually only returns 1), `Find` returns null (or an empty `IEnumerable`).

Not sure if that's universal - but it's pretty clear to me. `GetById`, `GetByName`, etc. presume a match exists (and usually a single match). `FindByEmail`, `FindByDepartment` don't presume that, and usually return 0:n matches.

I may make an exception for a method like `GetAll` that takes no parameters and returns 1:n matches, but throws an exception on 0.

Comment: Is it sort of a conventional naming and behaviour? Could you share a link or smth, please?

Comment: @Razor23Donetsk, at least about Java JPA: https://tuhrig.de/find-vs-get/